# Not All Notifications Show after being Offline

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing the case where I have a physical (**android**) device turned to airplane mode (without wifi). When I turn the device back to being online, I want to receive all notifications.

At the moment I am only receiving one of the multiple notifications.

I searched the documentation [Setting the lifespan of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl) about this case and find the **time_to_live** parameter. Through this parameter I can edit the lifespan of a notification but I am not using it, since by default it is set to 4 weeks. In my case, I am turning the device to online after a few seconds/minutes.

The following function is implemented within a callable Cloud Funtion which triggers and works fine when the device is online.

Here is how I send the messages:

```
async function notifyParticipantForRegistrationStatus(
  data: any,
  participantDeleted: boolean
) {
  const uid = data.uid;
  const courseId = data.courseId;
  const courseEventSnapshot = await firestore
    .collection("CourseEvents")
    .doc(courseId)
    .get();
  const courseEvent = courseEventSnapshot.data() as CourseEvent;

  // get tokens for this participant
  const registrationTokens: string[] = [];
  await firestore
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("Tokens")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        const tokenObj = doc.data() as Token;
        registrationTokens.push(tokenObj.token);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`registrationTokens: ${registrationTokens}`);
      console.error(error);
    });
  // transform date from utc to german
  const d = utcSecondsToGermanDate(courseEvent.start.seconds);

  // send notification to the deletedParticipant
  if (registrationTokens.length > 0) {
    const message = {
      notification: {
        title: `Kurs ${courseEvent.courseEventTitle}`,
        body: participantDeleted
          ? `Du wurdest vom Kurs ${courseEvent.courseEventTitle} an den ${d.getDate()}.${
              d.getMonth() + 1 //getMonth() starts from 0
            }.${d.getFullYear()} um ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()} entfernt. Deine Einheit wurde storniert.`
          : `Du wurdest zum Kurs ${courseEvent.courseEventTitle} an den ${d.getDate()}.${
              d.getMonth() + 1 //getMonth() starts from 0
            }.${d.getFullYear()} um ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()} registriert.`,
      },
      tokens: registrationTokens,
    } as admin.messaging.MulticastMessage;

    fcm
      .sendMulticast(message)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.failureCount > 0) {
          const failedTokens: string | string[] = [];
          response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
            if (!resp.success) {
              failedTokens.push(registrationTokens[idx]);
            }
          });
          console.log("List of tokens that caused failures: " + failedTokens);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution. Thanks to @sllopis I found out that the **notifications** are by default collapsible but **data messages** not. Thus, I did change my message to:

```
const message = {
      data: {
        title: `Kurs ${courseEvent.courseEventTitle}`,
        body: participantDeleted
          ? `Du wurdest vom Kurs ${
              courseEvent.courseEventTitle
            } an den ${d.getDate()}.${
              d.getMonth() + 1 //getMonth() starts from 0
            }.${d.getFullYear()} um ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()} entfernt. Deine Einheit wurde storniert.`
          : `Du wurdest zum Kurs ${
              courseEvent.courseEventTitle
            } an den ${d.getDate()}.${
              d.getMonth() + 1 //getMonth() starts from 0
            }.${d.getFullYear()} um ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()} registriert.`,
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      },
      tokens: registrationTokens,
    } as admin.messaging.MulticastMessage;
```

Now I was able to receive multiple "notifications" after getting the device online.

**Caution!!**

To catch and show such messages (data) when your app is in the background you have to use the **onBackgroundMessage** instead of the **onLaunch** and **onResume** functions. Here is an article that helped me with that: https://medium.com/@sylvainduch/firebase-messaging-catch-them-all-3f9c594734d7

For the **onBackgroundMessage** to fully work you have to follow the steps in the documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

and add to the newly created Application class the solution provided here: https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/238 by @varadkulk

at least for android.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain that you have read the first documentation, but I'm quoting it just for the record.

From [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl)

> FCM usually delivers messages **immediately** after they are sent. However, this might not always be possible. For example, if the platform is Android, **the device could be turned off, offline, or otherwise unavailable**. Or FCM might intentionally delay messages to prevent an app from consuming excessive resources and negatively affecting battery life.

> When this happens, **FCM stores the message and delivers it as soon as it's feasible**. While this is fine in most cases, there are some **apps for which a late message might as well never be delivered**. For example, if the message is an incoming call or video chat notification, it is meaningful only for a short period of time before the call is terminated. Or if the message is an invitation to an event, it is useless if received after the event has ended.

I believe that you can set your notification messages to be [non-collapsible](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages), which means that they are critical messages that will be delivered individually because every message has different content.

I also think that you might want to work with [high-priority FCM messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message), since this will reliably wake apps even when the device is in Doze.

Also see:

- https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#using_fcm
- [Receive all the push notifications when devices are offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522362/receive-all-the-push-notifications-when-devices-are-offline?rq=1)
- [Does FCM has a disadvantage that, if a device is offline, and message is triggered from FCM, the message is not received on device on coming online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166656/does-fcm-has-a-disadvantage-that-if-a-device-is-offline-and-message-is-trigger)
- [FCM push notification when subscribers offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606697/fcm-push-notification-when-subscribers-offline)
- [Is it possible for Android to retrieve FCM notification if the notification was sent when it was offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057049/is-it-possible-for-android-to-retrieve-fcm-notification-if-the-notification-was)

Comment: The property `time_to_live` should not be a problem in android, since by default it is set to four weeks. Moreover, I did study the documentation concerning the non-collapsible option. Apparently, there is no method to make notifications *non-collapsible* as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288118/how-to-make-a-gcm-fcm-notification-type-message-non-collapsible